# How to make canvas lines visible when dragging (no libraries, only vanilla JS, React.JS if necessary.)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, canvas

I'd like to add lines by two clicks, when moving the mouse the line should be visible. When click left mouse button again the line should be added. Only left button should draw.

How should I change my code to do this? (for now it allows to create lines,
but they aren't visible before mouseup).

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

```js
const canvasEl = document.getElementById('drawContainer')
canvasEl.style.position = 'absolute'
canvasEl.style.top = '12%'
canvasEl.style.left = '32%'

var lines = [], line;
const context = canvasEl.getContext('2d')
const collapseLinesBtn = document.getElementById('collapse_lines')


let startPosition = {x: 0, y: 0}
let lineCoordinates = {x: 0, y: 0}
let isDrawStart = false

const getClientOffset = (event) => { 
const {pageX, pageY} = event.clicks ? event.clicks[0] : event 
const x = pageX - canvasEl.offsetLeft
const y = pageY - canvasEl.offsetTop
return { x, y }
}

const initialDraw = () => { 

context.beginPath() //allows to prevent previously created lines from delete 
context.moveTo(startPosition.x, startPosition.y)
context.lineTo(lineCoordinates.x, lineCoordinates.y)
context.stroke()

line = [];
line.push([lineCoordinates.x, lineCoordinates.y]);
console.log(line)
}

const mouseDownListener = (e) => {
startPosition = getClientOffset(e)
//isDrawStart = true    // isDrawStart = true + clearCanvas() + initialDraw() from const mouseMoveListener = one visible line when dragging  + coordinates
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
context.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
}

const mouseMoveListener = (event) => {

if(!isDrawStart) 
  return
lineCoordinates = getClientOffset(event)
//clearCanvas()     
//initialDraw()   
//initialDraw(!isDrawStart()) 

}

const mouseUpListener = (e) => {
isDrawStart = false
context.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
context.stroke();
}

const clearCanvas = () => {
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasEl.width, canvasEl.height)
}

canvasEl.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownListener)
canvasEl.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveListener)
canvasEl.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpListener)

collapseLinesBtn.addEventListener('click', function clear() {
context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>    
    #collapse_lines {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 75px;
        left: 47%;
        padding: 10px 25px;
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
    </style>
    <title>Test Task</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main_container">
        <canvas id="drawContainer" width="700" height="700" style="border: 1px solid rgb(10, 10, 10)" ></canvas>
        <button id="collapse_lines">collapse lines</button>
    </div>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `mouseMoveListener` just do something similar as you do in your `mouseUpListener`, **without** setting `isDrawStart = false`:

```js
const mouseMoveListener = (event) => {

  if(!isDrawStart) 
    return
  lineCoordinates = getClientOffset(event)

  // Clear the canvas each frame
  clearCanvas()
  // Similar to mouseUpListener
  context.lineTo(lineCoordinates.x, lineCoordinates.y);
  context.stroke();
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but unfortunately it does not change the result. The lines are still invisible when mousemove (dragging) and appear only after mouseup (try to run my code in jsfiddle or similar). Could you check your hint please? 
Does anyone else have any other ideas? Thanks!